# How to translate and rotate coordinates?

Tags: graphics, rotation, translation, linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I have two 3D points `(x,y,z)`, namely **`A`** and **`B`** and a bunch of other 3D points. Point A is at `(0,0,0)`.

I would like to set point **`B`** to `(0,0,0)` so that all other points including **`A`** and **`B`** are translated and rotated in a way that is appropriate (so that A is no longer at `(0,0,0)`).

I know that there are some translations and rotations involved, but nothing more than that.

UPGRADE:
Point **`B`** is also constrained by three vectors: `x'`, `y'`, `z'` that represent `x`, `y`, and `z` axis of **`B`**'s coordinate system. I think these should be somehow considered for the rotation part.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate? I understand that you want to find a transform that maps `B` to the origin and `A` away from it. What are the three vectors of your *upgrade*? If this is the basis of the coordinate system, just use them as the matrix' column (or row) vectors and `B` as the fourth column / row. The inverse of this matrix should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As you have given two points, one (A) at the origin and one (B) somewhere else, and you want to shift (translate) B to the origin, I don't see the necessity for any rotation.
If you don't have any other contraints, just shift all coordinates by the initial coordinates of B.
You can construct a transformation matrix as given, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations for 2D, but if you simply translate, `R' = R + T`, where `R'` is the vector after transformation, `R` the vector before and `T` the translation vector.

For more general transformations including rotations, you have to specify the rotation angle and axis. Then, you can come up with more general transformation, see above link.